# "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol" Can't find solution

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been working on the following code for several weeks. But I've come across this error and despite the huge amount of identical problems I've googled, I still can't solve it. I would appreciate a lot if someone could help :)

On the TVideoIOYuv.cpp, inside *writePlane()* function I call *goToCorrectError()* function:

```
Bool writePlane(ostream& fd, Pel* src, Bool is16bit,
                   UInt stride,
                   UInt width, UInt height, bool temErro, bool chroma, TComPic*& pPic,
                   TComList<TComPic*>::iterator itPic, TComList<TComPic*>* pcListPic) 
{ 
   (...)
   goToCorrectError(itPic, pcListPic);
   (..)
}
```

In TVideoIOYuv.h I have declared goToCorrectError as

```
extern void goToCorrectError(TComList<TComPic*>::iterator itPic, TComList<TComPic*>* pcListPic);
```

since the function is defined in TAppDecTop.cpp as:

```
void goToCorrectError(TComList<TComPic*>::iterator itPic, TComList<TComPic*>* pcListPic)
{
TAppDecTop aux;
TComPic* dPic = getDamagedPic();
aux.CorrectsError(itPic, dPic, pcListPic);
}
```

and declared in TAppDecTop.h as:

```
(...)
#include "TLibVideoIO/TVideoIOYuv.h"
(...)
void goToCorrectError(TComList<TComPic*>::iterator itPic, TComList<TComPic*>* pcListPic);
```

When I try to compile I get the "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl goToCorrectError(class std::_List_iterator > >,class TComList *)" (?goToCorrectError@@YAXV?$_List_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@PEAVTComPic@@@std@@@std@@@std@@PEAV?$TComList@PEAVTComPic@@@@@Z)" error.

The funny part is that when I click "Go to Definition" over goToCorrectError on TVideoIOYuv.cpp it goes to its definition on TAppDecTop.cpp so it knows where it's defined. Thank you all :)

Comment: The compiler, the linker, and the IDE are different programs. It's very possible for the IDE to find a definition (because it's in your project) while the linker can't (because it didn't get compiled or isn't in the list of things to link).

Comment: Is TAppDecTop.cpp included as a source in your project?

Comment: @ drescherjm Yes it is.
@molbdnilo Well, the purpose of the question is to find an answer to that. How to make the linker find a definition of the function.. If you have any suggestion :)

Comment: Verify that the .obj file was created and it has the correct date / time.